# Spring Actuator InfoEndpoint.info() returns null during test and debug after converting maven to gradle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-actuator

I am converting a maven project to gradle. The project is a spring boot 3 rest api.

After converting most of the pom.xml to build.gradle, I am countering an issue that a test is not passing. This tests an endpoint that returns some value using `InfoEndpoint.info()` method of spring boot actuator. I tried application debugging and debugging the test itself using VSCode. `InfoEndpoint.info()` returns null in debug mode too. However, If I run the application using `gradle bootRun`, I can successfully access the endpoint without any issue. To summarize, the `InfoEndpoint.info()` returns nothing during test and debugging.

The test code is as follows

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes=Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class InfoControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    /**
     * Test the endpoint /info to get a information of git and build.
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    public void shouldReturnAInfo() throws Exception {
        // Send a GET request to the /info endpoint
        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(get("/info")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andReturn();
        String responseJson = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();

        ResourceBundle gitPropertyInfo = ResourceBundle.getBundle("git");
        ResourceBundle buildPropertyInfo = ResourceBundle.getBundle("META-INF/build-info");

        assertThat(JsonPath.parse(responseJson).read("$.git.commit.id", String.class)).isEqualTo(gitPropertyInfo.getString("git.commit.id"));
        assertThat(JsonPath.parse(responseJson).read("$.git.commit.message", String.class)).isEqualTo(gitPropertyInfo.getString("git.commit.message.full"));
        assertThat(JsonPath.parse(responseJson).read("$.git.commit.time", String.class)).isEqualTo(gitPropertyInfo.getString("git.commit.time"));
        assertThat(JsonPath.parse(responseJson).read("$.git.branch", String.class)).isEqualTo(gitPropertyInfo.getString("git.branch"));
        assertThat(JsonPath.parse(responseJson).read("$.git.dirty", String.class)).isEqualTo(gitPropertyInfo.getString("git.dirty"));
        assertThat(JsonPath.parse(responseJson).read("$.build.contact.about", String.class)).isEqualTo(buildPropertyInfo.getString("build.contact.about"));
        assertThat(JsonPath.parse(responseJson).read("$.build.contact.tel", String.class)).isEqualTo(buildPropertyInfo.getString("build.contact.tel"));
        assertThat(JsonPath.parse(responseJson).read("$.build.description", String.class)).isEqualTo(buildPropertyInfo.getString("build.description"));
        assertThat(JsonPath.parse(responseJson).read("$.build.version", String.class)).isEqualTo(buildPropertyInfo.getString("build.version"));
        assertThat(JsonPath.parse(responseJson).read("$.build.artifact", String.class)).isEqualTo(buildPropertyInfo.getString("build.artifact"));
        assertThat(JsonPath.parse(responseJson).read("$.build.name", String.class)).isEqualTo(buildPropertyInfo.getString("build.name"));
        assertThat(JsonPath.parse(responseJson).read("$.build.time", String.class)).isEqualTo(buildPropertyInfo.getString("build.time"));
        assertThat(JsonPath.parse(responseJson).read("$.build.group", String.class)).isEqualTo(buildPropertyInfo.getString("build.group"));

    }
}
```

The controller is as follows

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/info")
public class InfoController implements InfoApi {
    private InfoEndpoint infoEndpoint;

    // Constructor injection to inject the InfoEndpoint
    public InfoController(InfoEndpoint infoEndpoint) {
        this.infoEndpoint = infoEndpoint;
    }

    /**
     * Get information of build and git.
     * 
     * @return information of build and git.
     */
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Info> getInfo() {
        Map<String,Object> response = infoEndpoint.info();

        // InfoGit
        InfoGit infoGit = new InfoGit();
        Map<String, Object> responseGit = (Map)response.get("git");

        infoGit.setBranch(responseGit.get("branch").toString());
        infoGit.setDirty(responseGit.get("dirty").toString());

        // InfoGitCommit
        InfoGitCommit infoGitCommit = new InfoGitCommit();
        infoGitCommit.setId(((Map)responseGit.get("commit")).get("id").toString());
        infoGitCommit.setMessage(((Map)((Map)responseGit.get("commit")).get("message")).get("full").toString());
        infoGitCommit.setTime(((Map)responseGit.get("commit")).get("time").toString());
        infoGit.setCommit(infoGitCommit);

        // InfoBuild
        InfoBuild infoBuild = new InfoBuild();
        Map<String, Object> responseBuild = (Map)response.get("build");

        infoBuild.setDescription(responseBuild.get("description").toString());
        infoBuild.setVersion(responseBuild.get("version").toString());
        infoBuild.setArtifact(responseBuild.get("artifact").toString());
        infoBuild.setName(responseBuild.get("name").toString());
        infoBuild.setTime(responseBuild.get("time").toString());
        infoBuild.setGroup(responseBuild.get("group").toString());

        // InfoBuildContact
        InfoBuildContact infoBuildContact = new InfoBuildContact();
        infoBuildContact.setAbout(((Map)responseBuild.get("contact")).get("about").toString());
        infoBuildContact.setTel(((Map)responseBuild.get("contact")).get("tel").toString());
        infoBuild.setContact(infoBuildContact);

        // Info
        Info info = new Info();
        info.setGit(infoGit);
        info.setBuild(infoBuild);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(info, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

For reference here is the `build.gradlew`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id "org.openapi.generator" version "6.3.0"
    id 'jacoco'
    id "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties" version "2.4.1"
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
description = 'Description'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
  }
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform(org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES)
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.15.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.15.0'
    implementation 'org.openapitools:jackson-databind-nullable:0.2.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.0'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

springBoot {
    buildInfo {
        properties {
            name = 'Application name'
            additional = [
                'description': 'Description',
                'contact.about': 'About',
                'contact.tel': 'xxx-xxx-xxx'
            ]
        }
    }
}

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = "spring"
    library = "spring-boot"
    groupId = "${project.group}"
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/api/openapi.yaml"
    apiPackage = "${project.group}.${project.name}.generated.api"
    modelPackage = "${project.group}.${project.name}.generated.model"
    ignoreFileOverride = "$rootDir/.openapi-generator-ignore"
    configOptions = [
        interfaceOnly: "true",
        documentationProvider: "springdoc",
        useSpringBoot3: "true",
        additionalModelTypeAnnotations: "@lombok.AllArgsConstructor;@lombok.NoArgsConstructor"
    ]
}

openApiGenerators {
    include = [
        'stable'
        ]
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs += "$buildDir/generate-resources/main/src/main/java"
        }
    }
}

compileJava.dependsOn tasks.openApiGenerate

tasks.named('test') {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

What is wrong here and how do I fix it?